# How to debug "Lock wait timeout exceeded" in mysql (aurora)

Tags: mysql, debugging, transactions, mariadb, amazon-aurora

I'm getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded" error when inserting a record in MySQL table (amazon aurora to be precise). We're inserting hundreds of records in one transaction with savepoint for every few inserts.
We're using the InnoDB engine. We have `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` set to 50 sec. We're getting this error only in production so I am limited in debugging ability here.

I've tried to pull info about locked transactions when insert statements runs and here is what I got:

```
MySQL [(none)]> SELECT w.* FROM information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b ON b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id INNER JOIN information_schema.processlist p on b.trx_mysql_thread_id = p.ID LIMIT 10;
+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| requesting_trx_id | requested_lock_id        | blocking_trx_id | blocking_lock_id         |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| 1177444193        | 1177444193:5437:2161:286 | 1177444168      | 1177444168:5437:2161:286 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> select * from information_schema.innodb_trx where trx_id=1177444168 limit 10;
+------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
| trx_id     | trx_state | trx_started         | trx_requested_lock_id | trx_wait_started | trx_weight | trx_mysql_thread_id | trx_query | trx_operation_state | trx_tables_in_use | trx_tables_locked | trx_lock_structs | trx_lock_memory_bytes | trx_rows_locked | trx_rows_modified | trx_concurrency_tickets | trx_isolation_level | trx_unique_checks | trx_foreign_key_checks | trx_last_foreign_key_error | trx_adaptive_hash_latched | trx_adaptive_hash_timeout | trx_is_read_only | trx_autocommit_non_locking |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
| 1177444168 | RUNNING   | 2022-09-26 12:08:49 | NULL                  | NULL             |       1844 |            64308215 | NULL      | NULL                |                 0 |                 8 |              908 |                  1136 |            2579 |               936 |                       0 | READ COMMITTED      |                 1 |                      1 | NULL                       |                         0 |                         0 |                0 |                          0 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

As I see blocking tx isn't a query but rather some transaction with a lot of locked records because I see nothing in `trx_query`.

**So my question is how can I get more info about this blocking transaction to see what exactly is blocking my insert for 50 sec until timeout?**

p.s. we haven't had such problems on standalone MySQL but started to see lock wait errors when migrated to aurora.

Comment: It would be impossible to answer this question without more code and details.  Is it possible that you are not closing a transaction somewhere?